# Restore from XenServer LVM ddrescue image

Tags: lvm, xenserver

the disks in my xenserver are dying. I could rescue some of the lvm volumes  with ddrescue. Now I setup a new xenserer and I wonder how to restore from the rescued images. Anyone has experience with this?

Thanks a lot in advance,
grassu

Comment: Not so much. I don't no how to proceed. Unfortunately I cannot read the partition table inside the image with the gnu parted tool (it tells unrecognised disk label). So I cannot just mount the partion.

Comment: I created a backup of VG-Metadata with vgcfgbackup. Now I could restore the volumegroup with vgcfgrestore. But how to restore the lvm data into the new vg? Just with dd command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vgexport` and `vgimport` commands

Since you're dealing with LVM volumes, it's probably best to follow one of the many guides available for migrating LVM based storage to new volumes; I've found this particular site to be very useful: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I cannot use the lvm commands vgexport/vimport because of disc failures. I only could ddrescue some logical volumes from the the volumegroup. Now I don't know how to import the images in a new volumegroup. Any ideas?

Comment: They *should* just be block devices, in which case, you can try use dd to stream the data to a new block device. Are you able to access the volumes in any way currently?

Comment: So I can create a new lvm with same size as my rescue image on the new server and make a dd if=resuce.img of=/dev/VG_rescue/rescue? What about the lvm metadata? Will this work out of the box? The failing disk is still accessible (in parts). But exporting the vg is failing.

Comment: My understanding is that it should work - also make sure you set a reasonable block size - http://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd, else the operation could take some time. Not sure about the metadata - I don't think that will be an issue, since you're moving the volume to a newly created volume group; I don't think the metadata in this new volume group will be overwritten, for example. The operation is non-destructive to the source image/block device, so you won't lose any further data - just make sure the target device is the exact right one :)

Comment: will try and report